# How to search users in Cognito userpool in React Native app

Tags: react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building an app using React Native and Amplify (including authentication) and need to let users search for and follow other users also using the app.

The authentication flow is working fine, but I'm not able to search the cognito userpool for the list of users.

According to amplify-js/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/, one of the v1.0 functionality enabled "Search users in your pool using user attributes.", but so far I'm unable to find any additional documentation or examples.

I've tried using the Auth object from the aws-amplify module and the CognitoUserPool object from  the amazon-cognito-identity-js module, and neither seems to offer the search functionality.

How should I be going about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
        secretAccessKey: "YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: "YOUR_REGION"
    });
    
    const params = {
        UserPoolId: 'THE_USER_POOL_ID',
        AttributesToGet: [
          'email',
        ],
    };
    const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("data", data);
        }
    })
```

The problem now becomes having to store the access keys on-device, which I can't do.  Will likely create another table in Datastore to store user info for querying.